# Eloqua Cloud App - identify a customer

Tags: eloqua

I'm developing Eloqua application as described in https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/marketingcs_gs/OMCBA/

OAuth authorization and installation flow is working well, but I don't see any way to know who is this customer, who installed my application.

Is there a way to get company name or something like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following parameters in the Install url of your app to get user and site information from Eloqua:

- {SiteName}
- {SiteId}
- {UserName}
- {UserId}

e.g. https://client.example.com?site={SiteName}&user={UserName}

This is the official documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/marketingcs_gs/OMCAB/index.html#Developers/AppCloud/Reference/app-url-parameters.htm